# ChatClient websocket binding to events multiple times whenever socket re-connect

Tags: javascript, react-native, websocket

I'm using a simple [chat-client](https://github.com/ido-ofir/chat-client) for my react-native chat app which uses WebSocket.
Whenever there's an error on the server side and the chat shuts down, causing an error event on my app, sets the readyState to CLOSED meaning I need to restart and try to re-connect.

I have a list of listeners when the socket connects such as: 'chatMessage', 'error', 'userDisconnected', 'userConnected'.

But the problem is, whenever I recreate the client by doing:

```
    initWebSocket() {
        this._chatClient = null;
        this._chatClient = new ChatClient({
            url: `${Constants.chatUrl}:${Constants.chatPort}`,
            log: false
        });
    }
```

To then call a connect() afterwards, I create a duplicated event listeners of all of them. So when I send/receive a message, it shows twice as if it was indeed sent twice. This is a look & feel thing, because on the server, it only shows the message was sent once. If I go back to the message list screen and then get inside the same chat, it will update and show only 1 message, not 2. So this is 100% a duplicated event listener being called.

How can I solve this specific issue?